# Не могу сделать самообучающуюся нейронную сеть

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, формулы

вроде как написал рабочую нейронную сеть с учителем. Работало всё как положено. Но когда писал сеть без учителя, то ,по идее(как много где сказано и написано), входные данные должны были как-то классифицироваться, что у меня не получалось. Я брал код сети с учителем, менял только формулу изменения весов(на формулу Хебба, Хопфилда, Кохонена и другие). Сеть работает так: сначала даются данные, проходят сеть, по формуле веса меняются; можно остановить обучение и с текущими весами прогонять сеть. Ниже библиотека работы с матрицами и сама сеть. Библиотека работает нормально, выложил на всякий случай. Скажите, в чем проблема? Может формула не та, не та структура сети, может мало входных данных(или не подходящие), или так всё и должно быть?

Matrix.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

struct mat {
    float **m;
    int arr;
    int col;
    void create(int arr1, int col1) {
        m = new float*[arr1];
        for (int x = 0; x < arr1; x++) {
            m[x] = new float[col1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < col1; i2++) {
                m[i][i2] = 0.16 + static_cast<float>(rand()) / static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX / 0.8);
            }
        }

        arr = arr1;
        col = col1;

    }
    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < col; i2++) {
                cout << m[i][i2] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void createZeros(int arr1, int col1) {
        m = new float*[arr1];
        for (int x = 0; x < arr1; x++) {
            m[x] = new float[col1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < col1; i2++) {
                m[i][i2] = 0;
            }
        }

        arr = arr1;
        col = col1;

    }
};

void multMatrix(mat matrix1, mat matrix2, mat matrix3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix3.arr; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix3.col; i2++) {
            matrix3.m[i][i2] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix2.col; i2++) {
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < matrix1.col; i3++) {
                matrix3.m[i][i2] += matrix1.m[i][i3] * matrix2.m[i3][i2];
            }
        }
    }
}
void transpFirstMultMatrix(mat matrix1, mat matrix2, mat matrix3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix3.arr; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix3.col; i2++) {
            matrix3.m[i][i2] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.col; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix2.col; i2++) {
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < matrix1.arr; i3++) {
                matrix3.m[i][i2] += matrix1.m[i3][i] * matrix2.m[i3][i2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Neural net.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Math.h>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
//Functions
void CURSOR(int y, int x) {
    COORD p = { x,y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), p);
}
void st(char &s) {
    while (s!='q') {
        s = _getch();
    }
}

//Structures
struct Neurons {
    //Speed of learning
    float a = 1;
    void typeSpeed() {
        cout << "Введите коэффициент обучения" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        system("cls");
    }

    //Layers
    mat numOfNeurons;
    int numOfLayers = 0;
    void createLayers() {
        cout << "Введите число слоев" << endl;
        cin >> numOfLayers;
        system("cls");
        numOfNeurons.createZeros(numOfLayers, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfLayers; i++) {
            cout << "Слой " << i + 1 << endl << "Введите число нейронов" << endl;
            cin >> numOfNeurons.m[i][0];
            system("cls");
        }
    }

    //Weights
    mat *w;
    int numOfWeights = 0;
    void createWeights() {
        w = new mat[numOfLayers - 1];
        numOfWeights = numOfLayers - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            w[i].create(numOfNeurons.m[i + 1][0], numOfNeurons.m[i][0]);
        }
    }
    void printWeights() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            w[i].print();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    //Results
    mat *r;
    void createResults() {
        r = new mat[numOfLayers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            r[i].createZeros(w[i].col, 1);
        }
        r[numOfWeights].createZeros(w[numOfWeights - 1].arr, 1);
    }
    void printResults() {
        for (int i = 0; i < (numOfWeights + 1); i++) {
            r[i].print();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    //Errors
    mat *er;
    void createErrors() {
        er = new mat[numOfWeights];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            er[i].createZeros(w[i].arr, 1);
        }
    }
    void printErrors() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            er[i].print();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    //Test
    mat test;
    void createTest() {
        test.createZeros(w[0].col, 1);
    }

    //Functions teacher
    void geterr() {
        for (int i = 0; i < er[numOfWeights - 1].arr; i++) {
            er[numOfWeights - 1].m[i][0] = test.m[i][0] - r[numOfWeights].m[i][0];
        }
    }
    void conterr() {
        for (int i = (numOfWeights - 1); i == 1; i--) {
            transpFirstMultMatrix(w[i], er[i], er[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    void chwt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < w[i].arr; i1++) {
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < w[i].col; i2++) {
                    w[i].m[i1][i2] += a * er[i].m[i1][0] * r[i + 1].m[i1][0] * (1 - r[i + 1].m[i1][0])*r[i].m[i2][0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void got() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            multMatrix(w[i], r[i], r[i + 1]);
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < r[i + 1].arr; i2++) {
                r[i + 1].m[i2][0] = 1 / (1 + exp(-r[i + 1].m[i2][0]));
            }
        }
    }
    void learnt() {
        go();
        geterr();
        conterr();
        chw();
    }
    void practicet() {
        go();
    }

    //Creating neural netwowork
    void createNet() {
        createLayers();
        typeSpeed();
        createWeights();
        createResults();
        createPrResults();
        createErrors();
        createTest();
    }

    //Previous results
    mat *rpr;
    void createPrResults(){
        rpr = new mat[numOfLayers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            rpr[i].createZeros(w[i].col, 1);
        }
        rpr[numOfWeights].createZeros(w[numOfWeights - 1].arr, 1);
    }
    void inputPrResults() {
        for (int i = 0; i < (numOfWeights + 1); i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < r[i].arr; i2++) {
                rpr[i].m[i2][0] = r[i].m[i2][0];
            }
        }
    }

    //Functions noteacher
    void go() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            multMatrix(w[i], r[i], r[i + 1]);
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < r[i + 1].arr; i2++) {
                r[i + 1].m[i2][0] = 1 / (1 + exp(-r[i + 1].m[i2][0]));
            }
        }
    }
    void chw() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfWeights; i++) {
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < w[i].arr; i1++) {
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < w[i].col; i2++) {
                    w[i].m[i1][i2] += a * (r[i].m[i2][0] - rpr[i].m[i2][0])* (r[i+1].m[i1][0] - rpr[i].m[i2][0]);
                }
            }
        }
        inputPrResults();
    }
    void learn() {
        go();
        geterr();
        conterr();
        chw();
    }
    void practice() {
        go();
    }
};
struct teacher {
    int sq1[3][3] = {
        { 0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,1 },
    { 0,0,0 } };
    int r1[3] = { 1,0,0 };

    int sq2[3][3] = {
        { 0,1,0 },
    { 0,1,0 },
    { 0,1,0 } };
    int r2[3] = { 0,1,0 };

    int sq3[3][3] = {
        { 1,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0 },
    { 0,0,1 } };
    int sq4[3][3] = {
        { 0,0,1 },
    { 0,1,0 },
    { 1,0,0 } };
    int r3[3] = { 0,0,1 };

    void  in(mat input, int sq[3][3]) {
        int i3 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 3; i2++) {
                input.m[i3][0] = sq[i][i2];
                i3++;
            }
        }
    }
    void inTest(mat test, int r[3]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            test.m[i][0] = r[i];
        }
    }
    /*void teach(mat input,mat test) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
    in(input, sq1);
    inTest(test,r1);
    break;
    case 1:
    in(input, sq2);
    inTest(test, r2);
    break;
    case 2:
    in(input, sq3);
    inTest(test, r3);
    break;
    case 3:
    in(input, sq4);
    inTest(test, r3);
    break;
    }*/
    /*CURSOR(0, 0);
    n.input.print();
    n.errors2.print();
    cout << endl;
    n.errors1.print();
    cout << endl;
    n.results2.print();
    cout << endl;
    n.results1.print();
    cout << endl;
    n.w12.print();
    cout << endl;
    n.w23.print();
    cout << "Type H to stop learning" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    system("cls");
    */
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    //Variables
    char stop = 'e';

    //Initialization
    teacher t;
    Neurons n;
    n.createNet();

    //Main cycles
    //thread th(st, ref(stop));
    while (stop != 'q') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                t.in(n.r[0], t.sq1);
                t.inTest(n.test, t.r1);
                break;
            case 1:
                t.in(n.r[0], t.sq2);
                t.inTest(n.test, t.r2);
                break;
            case 2:
                t.in(n.r[0], t.sq3);
                t.inTest(n.test, t.r3);
                break;
            case 4:
                t.in(n.r[0], t.sq4);
                t.inTest(n.test, t.r3);
                break;
            }
            n.learn();
            CURSOR(0, 0);
            //n.printErrors();
            n.printResults();
            //n.printWeights();
            cout << "Type Q to stop learning" << endl;
            stop = _getch();
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    system("cls");
    //th.detach();
    while (stop != 'r') {
        int sq = 1;
        cout << "Номер квадрата:";
        cin >> sq;
        switch (sq) {
        case 1:
            t.in(n.r[0], t.sq1);
            break;
        case 2:
            t.in(n.r[0], t.sq2);
            break;
        case 3:
            t.in(n.r[0], t.sq3);
            break;
        case 4:
            t.in(n.r[0], t.sq4);
            break;
        case 5:
            stop = 'r';
            break;
        }
        n.practice();
        system("cls");
        CURSOR(0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i == 3 || i == 6) cout << endl;
            cout << n.r[0].m[i][0];
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        n.r[n.numOfWeights].print();
        CURSOR(4, 12);
        cout << "Горизонтальная линия";
        CURSOR(5, 12);
        cout << "Вертикальная линия";
        CURSOR(6, 12);
        cout << "Диагональная линия";
        CURSOR(8, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не разбирая ваш код -  сразу вопрос:. Есть обучение с учителем -  классификация один из ее вариантов. А есть обучение без учителя - в основном это кластеризация. И это существенно разные алгоритмы. Причем алгоритмов кластеризации есть много и разных. Как понять фразу "Но когда писал сеть без учителя, то ,по идее..., входные данные должны были как-то классифицироваться." Уж не перемешали-ли вы классификацию с кластеризацией??

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю, что такое кластеризация

Comment: Я правильно понимаю: классификация - деление объектов так, как хочет учитель, а кластеризация - деление объектов по признакам, которые нейронная сеть делит сама без помощи учителя?

Comment: Если так, то должна ли нейронная сеть без учителя чем-то ещё отличаться от сети с учителем кроме как формулой?

Comment: И как проходит процесс кластеризации? Я думал, что на вход должны подаваться данные объектов, а на выходе вероятностное отношение к какой-нибудь группе(то есть если объект относится к первой группе, то выход ,допустим, верхнего нейрона лучше всех других выходов приближён к единице)

Comment: А вы какую литературу используете при изучении нейронных сетей? Еще раз повторю -  классификация и кластеризация - это РАЗНЫЕ алгоритмы. Так что отличаются они не только "формулой". Ну, посмотрите, как это делается, например тут: http://dsp.vscht.cz/konference_matlab/MATLAB08/prispevky/025_dostal.pdf  тут http://www.kovera.org/neural-network-for-clustering-in-python/  или тут https://studfiles.net/preview/6069145/page:17/ И кстати, кластеризация с помощью нейронной сети - как правило, не самый эффективный путь решение проблемы.

Comment: И кстати, то что вы описали в последнем сообщении  - это вовсе не кластеризация, а нечеткая классификация.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю